# Async Await Progress Reporting Not Working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a C# WPF program that opens a file, reads it line by line, manipulates each line then writes the line out to another file.  That part worked fine.  I wanted to add some progress reporting so I made the methods async and used await with progress reporting.   The progress reporting is super simple - just update a label on the screen.   Here is my code:

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Title = "Select File to Process";
    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    lblWaiting.Content = "Please wait!";
    var progress = new Progress<int>(value => { lblWaiting.Content = "Waiting "+ value.ToString(); });
    string newFN = await FileProcessor(openFileDialog.FileName, progress);
    MessageBox.Show("New File Name " + newFN);
} 

static async private Task<string> FileProcessor(string fn, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fn);
    string newFN = "C:\temp\text.txt";

    int i = 0;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newFN))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //  manipulate the line 
            i++;
            sw.WriteLine(line);
            // every 500 lines, report progress
            if (i % 500 == 0)
            {
                progress.Report(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return newFN;
}
```

Any help, advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just marking your method as `async` has pretty much no effect on execution flow, because you're not yielding the execution ever.

Use `ReadLineAsync` instead of `ReadLine` and `WriteLineAsync` instead of `WriteLine`:

```
static async private Task<string> FileProcessor(string fn, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fn);
    string newFN = "C:\temp\text.txt";

    int i = 0;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newFN))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            //  manipulate the line 
            i++;
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(line);
            // every 500 lines, report progress
            if (i % 500 == 0)
            {
                progress.Report(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return newFN;
}
```

That will yield the UI thread and allow the label to be redrawn.

PS. The compiler should have raised a warning with your initial code, because you have an `async` method which does not use `await`.

Comment: OMG!  It worked!!! I'm so excited I'm finally starting to understand this async stuff.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!

Comment: Question... in my case, my app is just doing a crap-ton of CPU-bound calculations so there's no `ReadLineAsync`/`WriteLineAsync` I can await.  I thought this was where you use `await Task.Yield()` after updating the progress, but that didn't work.  I ended up using `await Task.Delay(1)` which *did* work, but just feels soooo wrong to me! So what is the proper way for a purely CPU-bound task?  If it makes any difference, it's started with this (renamed for clarity)... `var result = await Task.Run(() => HeavyCPUTask(progress));`