# Progress<T> class and problem with synchronization

Tags: c#, task, iprogress, reportprogress

```
Task Foo(IProgress<int> onProgressPercentChanged){
    return Task.Run(() =>{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            if (i % 10 == 0)
                onProgressPercentChanged.Report(i / 10);
            //Some operation
        }
    });
}

var progress = new Progress<int>(i => Console.WriteLine(i + " %"));
await Foo(progress);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

The above code prints my progress reports in the incorrect order. I suspected that this issue was related to synchronization, as when I add `Thread.Sleep(10)` at the `//Some operation` place, everything starts working correctly. How can I achieve correctness without the unnecessary `Thread.Sleep(10)`?

Comment: Just don't use Progress<> in a console mode app.  It doesn't do anything useful beyond the synchronization that is already built into Console.WriteLine().

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on your definition of "correctness".

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-7.0#remarks), progress handlers are invoked using the current synchronization context or (if there is none) the ThreadPool.

In theory, you could set up a synchronization context that tries to only have one active thread at a time, but that might defeat the purpose of using a Progress instance. If you want to make sure that each value is handled in order, you could use something more along the lines of an Observable, like `Subject` from `System.Reactive`:

```
async Task Foo(ISubject<int> onProgressPercentChanged)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            onProgressPercentChanged.OnNext(i / 10);
        //Some operation
    }
    onProgressPercentChanged.OnCompleted();
}


var progress = new Subject<int>();
using (progress.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i + " %")))
{
    await Foo(progress);
}
```

Or, if you need the multi-threaded nature of the Progress class, and you're okay with skipping some of the progress indicators, you can adjust your handler to make sure it doesn't go backwards.

```
object mutex = new object();
int latestProgress = 0;
var progress = new Progress<int>(i =>
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            latestProgress = Math.Max(latestProgress, i);
            if (latestProgress == i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " %");
            }
        }
    });

await Foo(progress);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class was designed having in mind environments with a special [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) installed, like WinForms and WPF applications. In those environments the `Action<T> handler` is going to be invoked in a synchronized fashion, without overlapping, and with FIFO order preserved. Console applications are not equipped with a `SynchronizationContext`, so the `Action<T> handler` is invoked on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), without any protection against concurrent or out-of-order executions. What you can do is to either install a proper `SynchronizationContext` on your console application, or use a custom implementation of the [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) interface, that invokes the `Action<T> handler` synchronously.

The first option requires the [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) NuGet package:

```
AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
{
    var progress = new Progress<int>(i => Console.WriteLine(i + " %"));
    await Foo(progress);
});
```

The `AsyncContext.Run` is a blocking call, similar to the [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run) method. It installs a special `SynchronizationContext` on the current thread, much like the `Application.Run` installs a [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext) on the UI thread.

For the second option see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777719/using-taskcompletionsource-within-an-await-task-run-call/59786280#59786280) answer (the `SynchronousProgress<T>` class).