# Cancellable progress form and cross-thread operations

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, thread-safety

I want to create a form that has a progress bar and a cancel button.  Code in my program will run an algorithm and update the progress bar.  I implemented a prototype (below) which works. I want to know if this is a correct implementation, or if there are better ways to do this. And in particular, I want to know if there are any issues with cross-thread access to the UI progress bar.  I have seen in the past that code can (appear to) run correctly, but when run under the debugger cross-thread exceptions are thrown.

Here's my basic form for implementing the cancellable progress bar.

```
    public partial class CancellableProgressForm : Form
    {
        public CancellableProgressForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int PercentComplete
        {
            set
            {
                progressBar.Value = value;
            }
        }

        private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

And prototype code for testing it on a form with a run button:

```
        private void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var progressForm = new CancellableProgressForm();

            var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
            {
                progressForm.PercentComplete = percent;
            });

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DoWork(progress);
                progressForm.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                progressForm.Close();
            });
            DialogResult dr = progressForm.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show($"Result={dr}");
        }

        // Prototype code to "do some work" and update the progress bar on the progress form
        private void DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                progress.Report(i);
            }
        }
```

As I said, the code runs fine with and without the debugger.  So why aren't cross-thread exceptions being thrown?  And is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The Progress class handles that internally.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that you can interact with a UI element only from the thread that created it. UI components are thread-affine. Not only they are not thread-safe, they are not even free-threaded. So be very careful with what you are doing inside the `Task.Run` delegate. Using a [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) is OK, because this component at the moment of its creation captures the synchronization context, and propagates all reports through the captured synchronization context, effectively enforcing the aforementioned thread-affinity rule.

What you have to do is to convert your event handler to [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), and `await` the `Task.Run`. After the `await` you are back on the UI thread.

```
private async void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellableProgressForm progressForm = new();
    progressForm.Show();

    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
    {
        progressForm.PercentComplete = percent;
    });

    await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

The code above is just a move towards the right direction, not a complete solution.

The `Progress<T>` class reports progress asynchronously, which is efficient because it doesn't slow down the background work, but it might produce some weird ordering artifacts. In case you run into problems, you could try the synchronous `IProgress<T>` implementation that I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777719/using-taskcompletionsource-within-an-await-task-run-call/59786280#59786280).

As for how to implement the cancellation functionality, you should make the `DoWork` cancellable by adding a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) parameter. See this article for details: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Another article that might be even more useful: [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

Comment: You may want to actually answer "So why aren't cross-thread exceptions being thrown?"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you are right, I should, since this is what the OP asked. But instead I focused on other problems in the code, that I believe are more important.

Comment: @Jimi no, I am not sure at all. I just added async/await in the existing code, and moved outside of the `Task.Run` the interaction with UI elements. The code in this answer is just a move towards the right direction, not a complete solution.

Comment: @Jimi I changed to code so that it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @Jimi there is some merit to keeping the `CancellableProgressForm` work-agnostic. This way you can use the same form with more than one types of work. Instead of overriding the `OnLoad` method, you can handle the public `Load` event and inject the work there.

Comment: Sure, it could be done like that. Maybe subscribing to the `Shown` event. You still need means to know whether the Cancel Button was pressed (could raise a public event), you have to remove or make unusable the [X] Button -- This is usually done with hooks, or in a mixed way, leveraging the ability to nest message loops. You could probably make use of an async pattern but, IMO, this introduces new complexity -- If you feel like it... :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a Task that's supposed to update a Form the way you're doing it now.
Even hoping that nothing goes wrong in the meanwhile, you want the Form that shows progress to be ready to handle the updates generated by the IProgress<T> delegate.
And you need to handle exceptions.

BTW, I've tested your code as it is and, as expected, it does throw when you try to access the Form class, setting its DialogResult.
The Property you have is accessed by the Progress<T> method.

My suggestion: run the `DoWork()` method from the `CancellableProgressForm`.
Now you have full control on what's happening there.

I've added a `CancellationTokenSource` that can cancel the progress.
The `DoWork()` method now accepts a `CancellationToken` that reports a cancellation request when the Cancel Button is pressed. The Dialog result is set, in this case, to `DialogResult.Abort`.

BTW, when you set a Form's `DialogResult`, this also closes the Form.
Since it's a modal Dialog, you need to dispose of it. This is done when `ShowDialog()` returns.

```
public partial class CancellableProgressForm : Form {
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public CancellableProgressForm() => InitializeComponent();

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => cts.Cancel();

    protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        bool errorState = false;
        var progress = new Progress<int>(percent => progressBar.Value = percent);
        try {
            await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress, cts.Token));
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            errorState = true;
            throw;
        }
        finally {
            cts?.Dispose();
            if (errorState) DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
        }
    }
}
```

The `DoWork()` method can be decoupled. It can be a member of the Form class or defined somewhere else, it doesn't share anything with any Form anyway.

```
private void DoWork(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken token = default) {
    int progressCount = 1;
    while (progressCount <= 100) {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        progress.Report(progressCount);
        progressCount += 1;
    }
}
```

In the calling Form, you just show the Dialog:

```
private void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var progressForm = new CancellableProgressForm()) {
        DialogResult result = progressForm.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show($"Result={result}");
    }
}
```

---

What's left: if the User closes the Form using the [X] Button (assuming it's visible)...  you can solve it with one line of code, or two. Three is still acceptable :) Just teasing, but you have to handle it.
Currently, if you close the Form while the Task is running, you get a `DialogResult.Cancel`. It may not be the *signal* you want, since the User didn't press the Button assigned to the Cancel action result explicitly